# C#, winform - NumericUpDown max limit not validated on KeyPress?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using NumericUpDown control of C# winform application.

Set Maximun value as 99. But when I type value above 99, eg: 555, it allows me to key (key_press event )in values 555 and it changes back to max value (99) only if i leave the control.  What i need is, user should not allowed to key in values more than 99. And also the default behaviour 'Up and Down action' values should not be affected by this.  How do i do this?

Comment: ((TextBox)numericUpDown1.Controls[1]).MaxLength = 2;

Comment: @hans Passant: You great man!! it works fine...,

Comment: @HansPassant: No doubt that's the best answer. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick idea:

```
public class StrictNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    protected override void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextBoxTextChanged(source, e);
        if (Value > Maximum)
        {
            Value = Maximum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought but would it not be cleaner to only call base.OnTextBoxTextChanged(...) if (Value < Maximum)?

Answer (score 1):

Use

> KeyUp

Event.

Or

`((TextBox)numericUpDown1.Controls[1]).MaxLength = 2;` // As Hans mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyDown event and validate the value when it fires.

Comment: tried, but it allows to key in values upto 3 digit, which ic more than 99...,

Comment: For me, `KeyDown` is not able to validate & negate the action; however, `KeyPress` is.

Answer (score 0):

When we have used numericupdown control in c#, with the keypress, keydown/up events when you wanted to restrict the digit length limit in control like 2,3,4 ...etc for the limit-1 digits you select the value in control using ctrl+shift+left or right arrow key combination and press numeric key for new value, it is working fine, but when you select all digits( length limit) the new numeric key is not able to enter in numericupdown control due to handling event below image:

[KeyDown event code snippet with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYSLF.png)

Hence, @ Hans Passant suggested type cast workaround is better to this problem.

Add this line in formload event or in `InitializeComponent()` method.

```
((TextBox)numericUpDown1.Controls\[1\]).MaxLength = 4;
```

For proper handling of 4 digits length limit in below code snippet:

[KeyDown event code snippet with Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb5ee.png)

Thanks! Hans Passant